# How to set value in lightning:combobox in aura lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, selectoption, default-value, lightning-combobox

<lightning:combobox aura:id="filterCaseType" label = "{!$Label.c.CPL_Event_Type}" name="caseTypes" placeholder="Case Type" options="{!v.caseEventTypeOptions }" onchange="{!c.filterCasesByType }"/>

caseEventTypeOptions  --> Is list of Key value pair

now values are Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday.....Saturday.

Now when page loads i want Tuesday to be selected by default. How can i achieve this in aura:lightning cmp on java script side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make use of the value attribute.

Check the below code

```
<lightning:combobox 
            name="Fruit" 
            label = "Select a Fruit" 
            value = "{! v.defaultVal }"
            placeholder = "Select Progress"
            options="{! v.options }" 
            onchange="{! c.handleChange }"/>
```

In the above code, defaultVal attribute holds the default value for the Combo Box.